# Issue with vlayout in ZK

Tags: exception, components, zk, zul

I am new to ZK. I have craeted a zul file which includes the vlayout component. Here is the entire code:

```
 <?page title="My Chart"?>

   <zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul
      http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul/zul.xsd">

    <vlayout apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('util.charts.LineChartVM')" >
       <chart id="chart" title="Half-Year Report" width="520" height="350" paneColor="#FFFFFF"
           type="line" yAxis="Amount"
           model="@bind(vm.model)" engine="@bind(vm.engine)" threeD="@bind(vm.threeD)"
       />
      <hlayout visible="@bind(not empty vm.message)">
         You clicked on :<label value="@bind(vm.message)"/>
     </hlayout>
    </vlayout>

  </zk>
```

Moreover I have added the following snippet in the pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
        <artifactId>zul</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

However when I go run the file I get the following error:

```
org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.DefinitionNotFoundException: Component definition not found: vlayout in [LanguageDefinition: xul/html],...
```

It looks like vlayout is not supported in the my version of zul. Does anyone know a possible solution to this issue? Has anyone had a similar experience?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the version of zk in your pom.
[Vlayout](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Layouts/Vlayout) is available since 5.0.4 but you are using 3.6.3
I guess the best will be to use 6.5.0, which is the newest zk.
But you need at least 6.0 cos you are using data binding.

Comment: I did it. However now I get the following error:
SEVERE: Failed to load jar:file:/home/John/workspace/jj-project/target/jj-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/zul-6.0.0.jar!/metainfo/zk/lang.xml
org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException:
etc...

What should I do? Thanks for the help

Comment: The best will be to use [ZK Studio](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkstudio) with zk 6.5. I do so and there are no problems with zk packages. I do not know what exactly is the problem, but you should check your zk path and deployment settings.

Comment: @Anto GO to your eclipse tmp0(Where your project copied by Ecipse) directory and delete this directory.Now Go to eclipse and right click on Server and click on clean it will deploy your project and again create same tmp directory inside eclipse folder .See it will resolve your issue otherwise tell me full stack trace.